# why pyautogui.typewrite() func ıs not workıng well?

Tags: python

[image is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X44BR.png)I am learning python pyautogui and the typewrite function does not work properly, it only works in the pycharm program, for example, I cannot write in google search bar with this function.

Comment: How do you know?  Show us your code.  How are you positioning the focus in the search bar?

Comment: before sleep time ends ım posıtıonıng  focus to the search bar  here is my code: import pyautogui
import time
time.sleep(3)
for i in range(10):
 pyautogui.typewrite("lol",interval=0.09)

Comment: Please modify your question to include new code, and do not use images of code.  Are you actually clilcking in the search bar?  Remember that just hovering the mouse doesn't change focus.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this instead:

```
pyautogui.write('your text')
```

Just make sure you have the search field selected or it won't work either.

Comment: İ tried  but its same again ,it works on only Pycharm

Comment: I only just saw your code example! I recreated and had success with "pyautogui.write('your text')"
Is your indentation correct?